# Grigori Mints' ADC method of proof search for a natural deduction in "sequent-style" calculus

Tags: logic, proof-theory, intuitionistic-logic, sequent-calculus

My question regards a proof search procedure, ADC, for a natural deduction in sequent style calculus:

- See Grigori Mints, [A short introduction to Intuitionistic logic](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=SBjvBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=a+short+introduction+to+intuitionistic+logic&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjUk-nUgcDUAhXEvxQKHaopAG4Q6AEIJDAA#v=onepage&q=a%20short%20introduction%20to%20intuitionistic%20logic&f=false) (2000): **2.6. Direct Chaining and Analysis into Subgoals**, page 15-16.

According to

- Grigori Mints and Shane Steinert-Threlkeld [ADC method of proof search for
  intuitionistic propositional natural deduction](https://oup.silverchair-cdn.com/oup/backfile/Content_public/Journal/logcom/26/1/10.1093_logcom_ext032/2/ext032.pdf?Expires=1497620977&Signature=FyNnNdRZGPZPa9DwqZxPDxM25cFNJWtdqULMtVUsvT9btP1BJaUhuFdSWR2TbuUdCKVqx1xPU~Kh-MdG0IFP7nPHjyt~z8udwqewBnBENyjpXgMz1cNIaxiC5EHbXMww9i3JtWQyWSgcbBa3OnfjycGPQkoXPBhjclRhDcnqn4kT~0ft4RHRyiUxU~xQSHDWLKm5ixYStYjH1e6ivuLlKOk~wic5SpO0t4-4sBTbsWdebQxUvmItio0r5BWYLTUvsK2eon2rmX4lfDqbXOJly8qlNRPxNI4sUyg-YjGEG7qgX4V1GPSkjiO~~8X55c2CS7xq1xeeDdZCPaYXHwiWJQ__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAIUCZBIA4LVPAVW3Q) (2016).

"the method proceeds first by $Analysing$ the sequent into sub-goals by applying all possible introduction rules, and then by checking whether each of these sub-goals can be established using only elimination rules ($Direct \hspace{0.1cm} Chaining$)."
The relevant elimination rules are
:
$$\frac{\Gamma \Rightarrow A \rightarrow B \qquad \Delta \Rightarrow A}{\Gamma, \Delta \Rightarrow B}\hspace{0.1cm} \rightarrow E \hspace{0.1cm}$$ 
$$\frac{\Gamma \Rightarrow A \land B}{\Gamma \Rightarrow A}\hspace{0.1cm}  \& E \hspace{0.1cm}$$ 
$$\frac{\Gamma \Rightarrow A \land B}{\Gamma \Rightarrow B}\hspace{0.1cm}  \& E \hspace{0.1cm}$$

> **DEFINITION 2.2**: $\textit{A deduction using only rules mentioned in} \hspace{0.1cm} \textbf{LEMMA 2.4.}, \textit{cut
> and structural rules is called} \hspace{0.2cm} \text{direct chaining}.$
>
> **Note**: A good heuristic for deducing $\Gamma \Rightarrow \alpha$ by direct chaining is to take $\Gamma$
>   as the initial set of data and saturate it by adding conclusions of all the
>   rules [$\textit{Mints means all elimination rules}$] except $\lor \Rightarrow$,
>   $$\frac{\alpha, \Gamma \Rightarrow \phi\qquad \beta, \Gamma \Rightarrow \phi}{\alpha \lor \beta, \hspace{0.2cm} \Gamma \Rightarrow \phi}\hspace{0.5cm} \lor \Rightarrow \hspace{0.1cm}$$ 
>   mentioned in $\textbf{LEMMA 2.4.}(see \hspace{0.1cm} below)$ plus cut (Example 2.5.), restricting
>   applications of $\bot_i$ 
>   $$\frac{\Gamma \Rightarrow \bot}{\Gamma \Rightarrow A}\hspace{0.5cm}  \bot_i \hspace{0.1cm}$$ 
>   to subformulas of $\Gamma, \alpha$ producing say $\Gamma_1 \equiv \Gamma^+$. Stop if $\alpha$ is
>   obtained, otherwise apply $\lor \Rightarrow$ bottom-up for each formula $\alpha \lor \beta \in \Gamma$, that is,
>   form $(\hspace{0.03cm} \alpha, \Gamma_1 \hspace{0.03cm})^+$ and $(\hspace{0.03cm} \beta, \Gamma_1 \hspace{0.03cm})^+$ Now add all formulas $\gamma \in (\hspace{0.03cm} \alpha, \Gamma_1 \hspace{0.03cm})^+ \cup(\hspace{0.03cm} \beta, \Gamma_1 \hspace{0.03cm})^+$  to $\Gamma_1$
>   forming $\Gamma_2$. Iterate the process till it stops.
>
> **LEMMA 2.4**: $ \text{(bottom of p.16)}\hspace{0.7cm} \textit{The following rules are derivable in Njp}$: $\rightarrow E, \hspace{0.1cm} \& E, \hspace{0.1cm} \neg E,\hspace{0.1cm} \bot_i, \hspace{0.1cm} \lor \Rightarrow \thinspace\text{(see above for most of these)}$
>   $$\frac{\Gamma \Rightarrow \alpha \longleftrightarrow \beta}{\alpha \lor \beta, \hspace{0.2cm} \Gamma \Rightarrow \alpha \longrightarrow \beta}\hspace{0.5cm} \longleftrightarrow E \hspace{0.1cm}$$ 
>   $$\frac{\Gamma \Rightarrow \alpha \longleftrightarrow \beta}{\alpha \lor \beta, \hspace{0.2cm} \Gamma \Rightarrow \beta \longrightarrow \alpha}\hspace{0.5cm} \longleftrightarrow E \hspace{0.1cm}$$
>   $$\frac{\Gamma \Rightarrow \neg \alpha\qquad \Delta \Rightarrow \alpha}{[\Gamma, \Delta] \hspace{0.2cm} \Rightarrow \beta}\hspace{0.5cm} \neg E \hspace{0.1cm}$$
>
> ---
>
> **ADC method of establishing deducibility:**  $\text{(top of p.16)}\hspace{0.7cm}$
>   One of the most straightforward methods of establishing deducibility of a
>   sequent $\Gamma \Rightarrow \alpha$ consists in its analysis into subgoals $\Gamma_1 \Rightarrow \alpha_1, ..., \Gamma_n \Rightarrow \alpha_n$ using
>   $\textbf{LEMMA 2.6.}$ ($\textbf{LEMMA 2.6.}$ is the deduction theorem: $\Gamma, \alpha \Rightarrow \beta$ iff $\Gamma \Rightarrow \alpha \rightarrow \beta$), and establishing each subgoal by direct chaining. We say that a
>   sequent $\Delta \Rightarrow \alpha \lor \beta$ is established when one of $\hspace{0.2cm}\Delta \Rightarrow \alpha, \thinspace \Delta \Rightarrow \beta \hspace{0.2cm}$ is established.
>   The combination of Analysis and Direct Chaining described above will be called
>   ADC-$\textit{method}$ or simply ADC.
>
> ---

-Mints and Steinert-Threlkeld furthermore claim ADC is

> "incomplete. For example, the sequent
>   p∨q⇒q∨p
>   obviously cannot be derived so that ∨+ is the last rule in the derivation"
>   $$\frac{\Gamma \Rightarrow A}{\Gamma \Rightarrow A \lor B}\hspace{0.1cm}  \lor + \hspace{0.1cm}$$
>   $$\frac{\Gamma \Rightarrow B}{\Gamma \Rightarrow A \lor B}\hspace{0.1cm}  \lor + \hspace{0.1cm}$$

- Question 1: Could anyone give a simple example illustrating the ADC proof procedure? In particular I do not understand the procedure described in the sentence starting "Stop if $\alpha$ is obtained", and the two sentences following it.
- Question 2: Clearly, p∨q⇒q∨p cannot be derived so that ∨+ is the last rule in the derivation. However, if we introduce the axiom p∨q⇒q∨p, then vacuously we have applied all introduction rules and elimination rules, and so, why shouldn't this qualify as a derivation by ADC? In any case, instances of axioms are obviously not excluded from proofs by ADC.
- Question 3: How can we determine, in general, which sorts of sequents are capable of a proof by ADC, and which are not? Could you give another example (or examples), $\textit{other than the examples they give}$ of a sequent which is not derivable via ADC? It would be useful to have at my fingertips some guidance as to when a proof via ADC is worth pursuing or not!
- Question 4: in an comment below it is pointed out that "the proof procedure is related to the well-know Prawitz's result about normalization: every deduction tree in ND can be written as a part with only elim rules followed by a part with only intro rules". What exactly is the relationship between ADC and normalisation. Do they differ in any significant way?

Comment: Basically, proof search in Sequent Calculus is bottom up; start from the goal and "unpack" it using rules. But in SC **all** rules are "introduction rules" (in the antecedent or in the consequent).

Comment: Mints' proof system (see page 10) is the so-called "Natural Deduction in SC-style": the rules are expressed with *sequents* but there are intro- and elim-rules, all "acting" on the consequent.

Comment: Thus, it seems that the procedure described by Mints is a proof search one "adapted" to the chosen style for the rules.

Comment: I understand this proof system and have worked in it. I don't yet have a firm grip of ADC, partly because it is atrociously described by Mints (with misprints I believe).

Comment: It seems to me that the proof procedure is related to the well-know Prawitz's result about *normalization*: every deduction tree in ND can be written as a part with only elim rules followed by a part with only intro rules (see page 397 of the paper). Thus, going bottom-up, we start from the goal and unpack it with elim rules: this may be the "analysis" part of the proof procedure. Why restricted only to $\to$-rules ?

Comment: I believe that the confusing point ("modulo" typos) is that in the 2000 booklet, the "procedure" is briefly exposed as a *pedagogical
device*, while the 2013 paper deal with an *algorithm*: see detailed exposition in Ch.2: only elimination rules; with $\lor$ we have branches,.. "Note that the ADC method is incomplete."

Comment: Could any of you provide an example of the process described here (in the above): "Stop if $\alpha$ is
obtained, otherwise apply $\lor \Rightarrow$ bottom-up for each formula $\alpha \lor \beta \in \Gamma$, that is,
form $(\hspace{0.03cm} \alpha, \Gamma_1 \hspace{0.03cm})^+$ and $(\hspace{0.03cm} \beta, \Gamma_1 \hspace{0.03cm})^+$ Now add all formulas $\gamma \in (\hspace{0.03cm} \alpha, \Gamma_1 \hspace{0.03cm})^+ \cup(\hspace{0.03cm} \beta, \Gamma_1 \hspace{0.03cm})^+$  to $\Gamma_1$
forming $\Gamma_2$. Iterate the process till it stops."

Comment: I have revised my question substantially

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider *Example 2.7*, page 12. We want to prove:

> $\Rightarrow (p \to r) \to [(q \to r) \to ((p \lor q) \to r)]$.

The first step in showing derivability is to apply *Lemma 2.6* "bottom-up" to analyze the goal.

Applying it three times, we get:

> $p \to r, q \to r, p \lor q \Rightarrow r$.

Now we need $\lor \Rightarrow$ to generate the two paths:

> $p \to r, q \to r, p \Rightarrow r \ \ $ and $ \ \ p \to r, q \to r, q \Rightarrow r$.

It is enough to prove one of the paths; consider the first one (the second is the same) and apply "Direct Chaining".

In order to show the derivability of $p \to r, q \to r, p \Rightarrow r$ we have to apply the elimination rules to the premises (the "saturation" step).

It is enough to consider a single application of $\to$-E:

$$\frac{p \to r \Rightarrow p \to r \qquad p \Rightarrow p}{p \to r, p \Rightarrow r}$$

followed by *weakening* to conclude the search procedure.

---

Now we can re-build the "normal" derivation (first all elimination rules, followed by introduction rules only):

1) $\dfrac{p \to r \Rightarrow p \to r \qquad p \Rightarrow p}{p \to r, p \Rightarrow r}$ --- $\to$E

2) $\dfrac{p \to r, p \Rightarrow r}{p \to r, q \to r, p \Rightarrow r}$ --- *weakening*

3) $\dfrac{q \to r \Rightarrow q \to r \qquad q \Rightarrow q}{q \to r, q \Rightarrow r}$ --- $\to$E

4) $\dfrac{q \to r, q \Rightarrow r}{p \to r, q \to r, q \Rightarrow r}$ --- *weakening*

5) $\dfrac{p \to r, q \to r, p \Rightarrow r \qquad p \to r, q \to r, q \Rightarrow r}{p \to r, q \to r, p \lor q \Rightarrow r}$ --- from 2) and 4) by $\lor \Rightarrow$

6) $\dfrac{p \to r, q \to r, p \lor q \Rightarrow r}{p \to r, q \to r \Rightarrow (p \lor q) \to r}$ --- $\to$I

7) $\dfrac{p \to r, q \to r \Rightarrow (p \lor q) \to r}{p \to r \Rightarrow (q \to r) \to ((p \lor q) \to r)}$ --- $\to$I

> 8) $\dfrac{p \to r \Rightarrow (q \to r) \to ((p \lor q) \to r)}{ \Rightarrow (p \to r) \to [(q \to r) \to ((p \lor q) \to r)]}$ --- $\to$I.

Comment: Thank you. :) I have again substantially revised and edited my question. I have added questions which relate to confusions on my part.